Vite components integration in older applications
I have a really big and old react application (using node 12.16.1). For clarity purposes let's say it's a Dashboard. It contains another React app (microfrontend) that has been upgraded to node 20 (Let's say it's the main page of the dashboard). And it uses another React+Storybook application for UI components such as buttons, modals and many others.
Would it be possible upgrading the React+Storybook to vite? I've seen in their documentation that it requires Node 18+. 20+.
Vite requirement
I have doubts as, even though the microfrontend has been upgraded, it's still embedded in a much older application.
I tried running the new storybook in the microfrontend and it works as Standalone.
Working Bullet component
But when working integrated in the bigger and older app:
I've seen it has issues parsing the .css
Parse error
The part in my webpack.config.js:
        {
          test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader'],
        },


There are different vite versions with different node requirements. If the latest says it needs 18+, you have no reason to not believe it. "Would it be possible upgrading the React+Storybook to vite?" - it's unknown what's your previous setup so nothing can be suggested. " I've seen it has issues parsing the .css" - the error means css loader isn't properly configured

Yep, but as I'm embedding the components into a microfrontend, it may be a different situation (as the microfrontend uses webpack and can be customized to be inside of this older app). And yep, everything points at the css loader not being properly configured. However my webpack.config looks fine (I'll attach it in the edited question) Ty for your feedback! @EstusFlask

"But when working integrated in the bigger and older app" - it's still unclear how exactly this setup works together. You'd need to run the apps together with the same Node version for this, which would likely create node-related errors, not just single webpack error, e.g sass loader for node 12  won't work in 20 without package version updates, and node packages that require 20 will result in syntax errors in 12
